# DAC output of the microcontroller does not increase after a point

Tags: dac

[This](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031020-stm32f405-415-stm32f407-417-stm32f427-437-and-stm32f429-439-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) uC board is supposed to have two 12-bit DACs.
But when I sweep from 0 to 4095, the DAC output stops increasing after around 4032 and settles to around 2.8V.

I power the board by its USB port.

What could be the reason for this?

**Edit:**

I want to increase the resolution.

On page 433 it is mentioned:
"An input reference pin, VREF+ (shared with ADC) is available for better resolution"

VDDA is an input which is an analog power supply. Absolute maximum ratings at page 203 of the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/dm00037051.pdf):

[image]

[image]

Does that mean if I power this board via VDDA pin with 4V DC, I can power the VREF+ with 4V(to increase the resolution)?

Comment: Check the electrical specs which are in the datasheet, not the reference manual. I'm not sure you can expect rail-to-rail anyways due to transistor voltage drops. Your DAC probably doesn't go to zero either.

Comment: Please see my edit. What do you think?

Comment: You're looking for the electrical specs *for the DAC* in that section.

Comment: What is the DAC output connected to?

Comment: Max is 3.6V, so you cannot safely supply 4.0 v.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I use analog input of this device to measure https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/evaluation-hardware-and-software/evaluation-boards-kits/adalm2000.html#eb-overview

Comment: Ignore the "Absolute Maximum" ratings section. Forget you ever saw it. It's not relevant to anything you might want to do with the device under normal circumstances. The DS explicitly tells you "These are stress ratings only and **functional operation of the device at these conditions is not implied**."

Comment: The manual you have linked is for the MCU, not the board. Look at the board's one, examine the schematic, noting whether there is any buffering on the DAC outputs. What you're describing sounds like someone chose the wrong opamp for that buffer, so it won't amplify close to its supply rails. If so, you need a rail to rail opamp ... or higher supplies for the opamp (NOT for the rest of the circuit)

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming you expect the output to be ideal but it isn't.

It is perfectly normal for the output to not reach GND or supply voltage.

How close it goes depends on if you use the onboard DAC buffer op-amp or not, and how much load you have on the DAC output pin.

See the DAC characteristics part of the MCU datasheet.

Comment: Please see my edit. What do you think?

Comment: What I think is that it's absolutely poor idea to raise supply voltage beyond recommended ratings where it may not function properly to the limit of absolute maximum rating at which there is already a risk of permanent damage.